# How do I convert a JTextField string to a double?

Tags: java, string, double, jtextfield

My program works with birthday's and age's. I have trouble with trying to convert my JTextField strings to doubles. I used the parse method but still received a error. Please Help!

```
public class MyPaymentFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JTextField txtAge;
    JTextField txtDate;

        public MyPaymentFrame()  {
        Container mycnt = getContentPane();
        mycnt.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        Color c = new Color(56, 100, 20);
        Font F = new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 20);

        mycnt.add(new JLabel("Enter your Age"));
        txtAge = new JTextField(15);
        mycnt.add(txtAmount);


        mycnt.add(new JLabel("Enter birthdate"));
        txtDate = new JTextField(10);
        mycnt.add(txtDate);

    }
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Clear")) {
            txtAge.setText("");
            txtDate.setText("");
        }

        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Calculate")) {
            // Converting String to Double
            double Amount = Double.parseDouble(txtMonth);

        }

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Theframe myframe = new Theframe();

    }

}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Did you try printing `txtMonth` to troubleshoot...? it should be the first step....

Comment: The code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently txtMonth is a JTexfield, but the Double.parseDouble method receives a String. Check the method's javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)).

Try using:

```
double Amount = Double.parseDouble(txtMonth.getText());
```

Also, this method will throw a NumberFormatException if the text can't be converted to double.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
    Double Amount = Double.valueOf(txtMonth);
```

According to the documentation:

This method returns a `Double` object holding the double value represented by the argument `String`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 double Amount = Double.parseDouble(txtMonth.getText());
```

or

```
Double Amount = Double.valueOf(txtMonth.getText());
```

`parseDouble()` returns a primitive `double` value. `valueOf()` returns an instance of the wrapper class`Double`.

Before Java 5 introduced autoboxing, that was a very significant difference between these two.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the text of the object `txtMonth` by calling the method `getText`  AND please validate the input or use a Try catch falls the input is not valid...

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double amount=0.0;
    try {
         amount = Double.parseDouble(txtMonth.getText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ups, this was not castable to double");
          amount=-10.0;
    }
    System.out.println("Here is the double: "+ amount);
}
```